# CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual Studio 15 2017 (while running Verification Scripts for intel openVINO toolkit)

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017, intel, openvino

i have installed all dependencies as requires for Intel OpenVINO Toolkit.
as shown in guidelines of installation of OpenVINO toolkit for windows10.
https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_windows.html

after installation while running verification script i am getting this error.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino_2019.3.379\deployment_tools\demo>demo_squeezenet_download_convert_run.bat`

```
Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
Creating Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 files in C:\Users\omiz\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\inference_engine_samples_build...
CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual Studio 15 2017

Generators
  Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2013 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 11 2012 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2012 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 10 2010 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2010 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Visual Studio 9 2008 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2008 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Visual Studio 8 2005 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2005 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64".
  Visual Studio 7 .NET 2003    = Generates Visual Studio .NET 2003 project
                                 files.
  Visual Studio 7              = Deprecated.  Generates Visual Studio .NET
                                 2002 project files.
  Visual Studio 6              = Deprecated.  Generates Visual Studio 6
                                 project files.
  Borland Makefiles            = Generates Borland makefiles.
  NMake Makefiles              = Generates NMake makefiles.
  NMake Makefiles JOM          = Generates JOM makefiles.
  Green Hills MULTI            = Generates Green Hills MULTI files
                                 (experimental, work-in-progress).
  MSYS Makefiles               = Generates MSYS makefiles.
  MinGW Makefiles              = Generates a make file for use with
                                 mingw32-make.
  Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  Watcom WMake                 = Generates Watcom WMake makefiles.
  CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeLite - MinGW Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - NMake Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles
                               = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - NMake Makefiles
                               = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Kate - MinGW Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - NMake Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - MinGW Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - NMake Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.

Error
```